# Getting answer from Jabber Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xmpp

I want connect with my jabber server and read server answer:

```
       DnsEndPoint host = new DnsEndPoint("talk.google.com", 5222);
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

public void start()
{
 string message = "<?xml version=1.0?><stream:streamto='gmail.com'xmlns='jabber:client'xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'version='1.0'>";

            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            args.RemoteEndPoint = host;
            args.Completed += SocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed;
            args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            bool completesAsynchronously = socket.ConnectAsync(args);

            if (!completesAsynchronously)
            {
                SocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed(args.ConnectSocket, args);
            }
}

 private void SocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Error during socket operation: " + e.SocketError));
                return;
            }
            byte[] buffer = e.Buffer;
            XDocument temp = ConvertByteArrayToXml(buffer);

        }

XDocument ConvertByteArrayToXml(byte[] data)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                return XDocument.Load(reader);
            }
        }
```

At Return `XDocument.Load(reader)` I get exeption `'1.0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''`. How can solve it?

Why I want it? Because when I authorize myself and change status it not affect it at  my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (in your declaration for `message`):

```
<?xml version=1.0?>
```

is an invalid XML declaration. As per the exception, you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Note that this has nothing to do with Jabber or sockets, and everything to do with XML. It's important to pay attention to exception messages and stack traces, so you can diagnose this sort of thing for yourself: you need to be able to isolate the *area* of the problem, so you can tackle just that one bit in isolation.

(The rest of that XML looks pretty bust, too, by the way.)

Comment: @Dudi: It's not from a Google server - you've got that string hard-coded in your program!

Comment: Right! I fix it and now I got `The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D, cannot be included in a name.`

Comment: @Dudi: Yes, as I edited to say: your XML is invalid in various ways. Fix it. Presumably you copied this as an example from somewhere, but look for other examples. (It's not clear why you're parsing the message that you're *sending* in the first place, to be honest. Your code is a bit confused at the moment.)

Comment: Ok now I think my message is acceptable because now I get `Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: stream` I can't close it because then I close session.

Comment: See my answer.  You MUST parse the XML incrementally, not as a document.  In C#, this can be a little tricky, due to the buffering that the various incremental parsers use.

Answer (score 4):

**Please** do not write your own XMPP library from scratch, but choose one of the [existing ones](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

You're not going to be successful thinking of the XML you receive like a file, which is where your `Unexpected end of file has occurred` error is coming from.  You **must** parse the XML incrementally.

Comment: There is one for windows phone?