# How to send parsed XML to XMPP server

Tags: c#, xmpp, windows-phone-7.1

This is a new question from [Getting anwser from Jabber Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344866/getting-anwser-from-jabber-server/11353210#11353210)

> You're not going to be successful thinking of the XML you receive like
>   a file, which is where your Unexpected end of file has occurred error
>   is coming from. You must parse the XML incrementally.

Ok my question is how? How can I send not closed pice of xml?

Should I serializ object and then send?

BTW. I can't use existing lib because there isn't at Windows Phone 7.5.

Comment: there are libs for Windows Phone 7.X. You find them from here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: @Alex Could you name one? Because I don't see any one.

Comment: MatriX and IP*Works for example. The other Open Source libs will also work with some modifications if they are compatible with your licensing.

Comment: Matrix is for $ and IP*Works as well.

Comment: I'm going to mod myself down for this, but if you can't figure this part out, you're not going to be successful with the harder bits that come later, like implementing SASL.  Seriously, to get around this in JabberNet, I ended up porting James Clark's XP to C#, which was non-trivial.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand ok but how I could use JabberNet in Windows Phone? Because only thing coming to my mind is decompile jabber-net.dll?

Comment: Source is here: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/.  NOTE: LGPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate on the explanation with an example (with snippets taken from [here](http://ceit.uq.edu.au/content/how-xmpp-works-step-step)).

> You're not going to be successful thinking of the XML you receive like
>   a file, which is where your Unexpected end of file has occurred error
>   is coming from. You must parse the XML incrementally.

When you connect to an XMPP, you open a connection to the server. To do this, you send something like the following...

```
<stream:stream
  to='example.com'
  xmlns='jabber:client'
  xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
  version='1.0'>
```

...let's ignore authentication for the moment and just assume that this works. You'll notice that this one section alone is not valid XML (the  element is not closed). However, for XMPP, that's okay. The server will send back it's own messages to tell you that you're good to go. Now we know that we can send our message stanzas. We type out our message, then send...

```
<message from='juliet@example.com' to='romeo@example.net'>
    <body>Romeo, romeo...</body>
</message>
```

After a few seconds, we decide to go offline...

```
    <presence type='unavailable'/>
</stream:stream>
```

Now let's look at what we sent...

```
<stream:stream
      to='example.com'
      xmlns='jabber:client'
      xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
      version='1.0'>

    <!-- A few seconds elapsed -->

    <message from='juliet@example.com' to='romeo@example.net'>
        <body>Romeo, romeo...</body>
    </message>

    <!-- A few seconds elapsed -->

    <presence type='unavailable'/>
</stream:stream>
```

So, in the end, you can think of the interaction with the server as if you are creating a document that EVENTUALLY becomes a fully valid XML document. And this is a nice way to think about things when you're first learning about XMPP.

However, you're creating this document over a period of time, not all at once. XML libraries typically don't think that you're only going to create PART of the document now: they're concerned with creating the entire document at once. This is why traditional XML libraries may not be helpful for you in writing XMPP programs. Additionally, a simple XML library won't be able to deal with extra information such as authentication logic.

In the end, you COULD write your own library. However, you would need to be very careful in your selection of tools (as like I said before, XML libraries might not be able to handle these partial XML creations).

Anyway, in the end, your question is...

`How can I send not closed pice of xml?`

And the answer is: find a library to do it for you. And I don't mean just the XML parts: I mean all of XMPP. The right library will not even need you to concern yourself with the fact that XML even exists unless you get really advanced. If you can't find a library...

1. Look harder. Spending a day looking for a library is STILL less time than a month making your own.
2. See if you can find an open-source library that does most of what you want. Then, work around the parts that are different, or make your own source code changes to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

The XMPP protocol is based on XML code. Basically it com's til this. A connection with the server is made by using a opening tag  and than after authenticating, more XML messages are send to and from the server, thay are called stanza. After you are finished with the server the XML "file" is closed with a closing tag. . Then the server closes the socket. And so you can send XML code without closing the "file".
Hope this helps you understand.